# My js function to hide and show isn't working on mobile

Tags: javascript

I've got some basic javascript that isn't working on mobile devices, but works for all other device types.

I've got a section with a burger menu in it, and an article below that with content that's supposed to be hidden, then shown when the user clicks the burger menu:

```
<section id="nav">
    <a href="#modal-menu" id="modal-opener">
      <span id="b1" class="burger"></span>
      <span id="b2" class="burger"></span>
      <span id="b3" class="burger"></span>
    </a>


  <article id="modal-menu">
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <a href="#" id="modal-closer">x</a>
  </article>
</section>
```

Then this js hides the article and shows it on click;

```
function whatevsd(){
    document.getElementById("modal-menu").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("modal-opener").addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("modal-menu").style.display = "block";
    });
}
whatevsd();
```

I even tried adding touchstart, as in:

```
function whatevsd(){
    document.getElementById("modal-menu").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("modal-opener").addEventListener("touchstart", function(){
        document.getElementById("modal_menu").style.display = "block";
    });
}
whatevsd();
```

But that didn't change anything. Any ideas?

Edit:

Snippet on request:

```js
function whatevsd(){
    document.getElementById("modal-menu").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("modal-opener").addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("modal-menu").style.display = "block";
    });
}
whatevsd();


function whatevsd(){
    document.getElementById("modal-menu").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("modal-opener").addEventListener("touchstart", function(){
        document.getElementById("modal-menu").style.display = "block";
    });
}
whatevsd();
```

```css
#modal-opener{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
  background: green;
  z-index: 99;
}

#modal-menu{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
  background: orange; 
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section id="nav">
    <a href="#modal-menu" id="modal-opener">
      <span id="b1" class="burger"></span>
      <span id="b2" class="burger"></span>
      <span id="b3" class="burger"></span>
    </a>


  <article id="modal-menu">
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <a href="#" id="modal-closer">x</a>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: you mean to say you are running  this on mobile browser ?

Comment: Is both the iOS and android 's browser didn't work?

Comment: I've tried it on dev tools on my laptop, and on a browser on my android, but it doesn't work on either.

Comment: It's getting the ```display none``` but it's not getting the click event. Nothing changes, when you click on ```modal-opener```

Comment: Please add the CSS to turn this into a [mre]. Use the `<>` button when editing the question.

Comment: I'm also testing your code on mobile (Android / Firefox) and it works fine, as expected: https://jsbin.com/dozecibija/edit?output

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. It's not clear which button I should be using when editing the question.

Comment: It's the seventh button in the body section. It allows you to insert a runnable snippet. Kinds pointless since this is specifically about mobile browsers but since your current code works as expected, something else must be causing this. Most likely: CSS making an element cover the button (also you need to @ me when replying or I won't get notified, like @tdrsam)

Comment: ChrisG 's jsbin example works fine on my edge's dev tool

Comment: Thanks to everyone who's trying to help. I added the requested snippet. There's nothing covering the button, there's nothing in the way. It's not looking good right now though. Maybe I try scrapping everything and starting again.